# How can I change the color changing the state from redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to change a specific icon color in a map when I click on it, but the ***color doesn't change***, I already did a little project that changes the color when I click on it, but the difference between them is: In this [project](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-lederberg-p76ov?file=/src/App.js) I used `useState`, and here I'm using the Redux State and I don't know how can I do this.

```
function handleRetweetColor(id) {
  console.log("ID: " + id);
  props.post.postReducer.map(post => {
   if(post.id === id) {
     console.log(post)
     return { ...post, retweet: true }
   }
   return post;
  })
}

return (
    <div className="posts-container">
      {props.post.postReducer.map(post => {
      return (
        {console.log(post)} <------ value in the image
        <div className="post" key={post.id}>
          <div className="bottom-content">
            <div onClick={() => handleRetweetColor(post.id)} >
              <FaRetweet size={20} style={{ color: post.retweet ? "#35e95f" : "#ccc" }} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })}
  </div>
)
```

[Object that returns in the log above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqVxp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handleRetweetColor` function does not return anything. But even if it did, you do nothing with it. You just call it on `click`.

If you want to update the redux store, you would need to call an `action` and pass the `id` with it, and in your reducer you would change the redux store to set the `retweet` to true.